# Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Framework.Logging.ILoggerFactory' or one of its dependencies

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-core, visual-studio-2015

In my new asp.net 5 app, I have this error:

> Could not load file or assembly
>   'Microsoft.Framework.Logging.ILoggerFactory' or one of its
>   dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified
>
> System.IO.FileNotFoundException Could not load file or assembly
>   'Microsoft.Framework.Logging.ILoggerFactory, Version=0.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies. The
>   system cannot find the file specified.

However I already added the reference on the project.json

```
{
  /* Click to learn more about project.json  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=517074 */
  "webroot": "wwwroot",
  "version": "1.0.0-*",
  "dependencies": {
       "EntityFramework.SqlServer": "7.0.0-beta4",
        "EntityFramework.Commands": "7.0.0-beta4",
        "Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc": "6.0.0-beta4",
        "Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.TagHelpers": "6.0.0-beta4",
        "Microsoft.AspNet.Authentication.Cookies": "1.0.0-beta4",
        "Microsoft.AspNet.Authentication.Facebook": "1.0.0-beta4",
        "Microsoft.AspNet.Authentication.Google": "1.0.0-beta4",
        "Microsoft.AspNet.Authentication.MicrosoftAccount": "1.0.0-beta4",
        "Microsoft.AspNet.Authentication.Twitter": "1.0.0-beta4",
        "Microsoft.AspNet.Diagnostics": "1.0.0-beta4",
        "Microsoft.AspNet.Diagnostics.Entity": "7.0.0-beta4",
        "Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework": "3.0.0-beta4",
        "Microsoft.AspNet.Server.IIS": "1.0.0-beta4",
        "Microsoft.AspNet.Server.WebListener": "1.0.0-beta4",
        "Microsoft.AspNet.StaticFiles": "1.0.0-beta4",
        "Microsoft.AspNet.Tooling.Razor": "1.0.0-beta4",
        "Microsoft.Framework.ConfigurationModel.Json": "1.0.0-beta4",
        "Microsoft.Framework.ConfigurationModel.UserSecrets": "1.0.0-beta4",
        "Microsoft.Framework.CodeGenerators.Mvc": "1.0.0-beta4",
        "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.BrowserLink.Loader": "14.0.0-beta4",
        "Microsoft.AspNet.Security.OpenIdConnect": "1.0.0-beta3",
       "Microsoft.Owin.Security.Cookies": "3.0.1",
      "Microsoft.Framework.Logging.Console": "1.0.0-beta4" 
  },
  "commands": {
    /* Change the port number when you are self hosting this application */
    "web": "Microsoft.AspNet.Hosting --server Microsoft.AspNet.Server.WebListener --server.urls http://localhost:5000",
    "gen": "Microsoft.Framework.CodeGeneration",
    "ef": "EntityFramework.Commands"
  },
  "frameworks": {
    "dnx451": { }
  },
  "exclude": [
    "wwwroot",
    "node_modules",
    "bower_components"
  ],
  "bundleExclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "bower_components",
    "**.kproj",
    "**.user",
    "**.vspscc"
  ],
  "scripts": {
    "postrestore": [ "npm install" ],
    "prepare": [ "grunt bower:install" ]
  }
}
```

what am I missing?

weird thing is that it builds!

Comment: did you run `dnu restore` before `dnu build`?

Comment: Also you have some beta3 packages which will be confused under beta4 runtime. Better to use beta4 of those.

Comment: how? I just press F5 in visual studio

Comment: Right click on references and chose the option to restore the packages. It should happen but it sometimes gets stuck (beta software :)).

Comment: If I put this: to beta4,   "Microsoft.AspNet.Security.OpenIdConnect": "1.0.0-beta4",
      , then I get tons of errors like this: Severity Code Description Project File Line
Error CS0234 The type or namespace name 'Security' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft.AspNet' (are you missing an assembly reference?) WebApplication2.DNX 4.5.1 C:\Proyectos\WebApplication2\src\WebApplication2\Controllers\AccountController.cs 4

Comment: Can you put this project up on github or somewhere so that I can have a look?

Comment: just download this one AS IS to reproduce it: https://github.com/AzureADSamples/WebApp-OpenIdConnect-AspNet5

Comment: or this one too https://github.com/jwood803/AzureADTest, issue already reported here: https://github.com/AzureADSamples/WebApp-OpenIdConnect-AspNet5/issues/1

Comment: I'm stuck with this, myself. I removed instances of `Microsoft.Framework.Logging' that was in the solution and it still gives the error.

Comment: at least the error is for many people and  not only myself, then I hope we get some attention.

Comment: It looks like you've upgraded from beta3 - there's one reference still there, and the 'Security' namespace was updated to the 'Authentication' namespace, along with a number of other changes.

Comment: if I change Microsoft.AspNet.Security.OpenIdConnect from beta3 to beta4, then project will not build anymore and I will have lots of errors.

Comment: please see screenshot here: http://screencast.com/t/iwEsZNvx

Comment: Thanks @MattDeKrey! I've updated to the latest beta here - https://github.com/jwood803/AzureADTest. Though it seems to run now it's just a blank page, but I'll continue with it.

Comment: Now I understand your comment and it seems I am closer to the solution, I changed  this package      "Microsoft.AspNet.Authentication.OpenIdConnect": "1.0.0-beta4", but still get some compile programs after changing some usings http://screencast.com/t/vuadadKylMdS

Comment: how can we move this question to the chat?? seems its extended

Comment: I used jon code from your example but instead of a blank page I got this: http://screencast.com/t/88u1EqvCrT @Jon

Comment: Interesting. I still got a blank page but no breakpoints on the controllers are hit. Maybe we can take this to the chat - http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/43899/asp-net

Comment: Was there any resolution to this?

Comment: I think you need to add a reference in your project.json to Microsoft.Framework.Logging as well, not only Microsoft.Framework.Logging.Console.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should update to the latest version (Beta 7 at the time of writing, although Beta 8 is out next week). Beta 4 is a few versions out of date now and was pretty unstable.

As suggested by @Geerten, you need to add `Microsoft.Framework.Logging` too. You can find out more about upgrading to Beta 7 from the official [announcement](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2015/09/02/announcing-availability-of-asp-net-5-beta7.aspx). Note that Beta 7 had new versions of the tooling too, so you need to install that.